# Devise sign up not working on Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am working on a rails app. I use devise for auth. I added name,surname,phone,schoolNumer variables to User. When press sign up button nothing happens just refreshing page. But login button is working. What is the problem?

registrations/new.html.erb

```
<div class="login-dark">
  <form method="post">
    <div class="illustration"><%= image_tag('paulogo.png') %></div>

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>


    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "name", placeholder:"Name", class:"form-control" %>
    </div>


    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= f.text_field :surname, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "surname", placeholder:"Surname", class:"form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= f.number_field :phone, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "phone", placeholder:"Phone Number", class:"form-control" %>
    </div>

      <div class="field form-group">
      <%= f.number_field :schoolNumber, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "school number", placeholder:"School Number", class:"form-control"%>
    </div>

    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", placeholder:"Email", class:"form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field form-group">
      <% if @minimum_password_length %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder:"Password (Min ".concat(@minimum_password_length.to_s)+ " Characters)", class:"form-control"%>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", placeholder:"Password Confirmation", class:"form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Sign up", class:"btn btn-primary btn-block"%>
    </div><div class="center_div">
      <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

    </div>
    <% end %>

  </form>
</div>
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:surname])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:surname])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:phone])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:phone])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:schoolNumber])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:schoolNumber])

  end
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

And db/migrate/AddDetailsToUser.rb

```
class AddDetailsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :name, :string
    add_column :users, :surname, :string
    add_column :users, :phone, :integer
    add_column :users, :schoolNumber, :integer
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    post '/users/sign_up' => 'devise/registrations#create'
  end
  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
  resources :users, only: [:show]

  root to: "pages#home"
  get '/about', to: 'pages#about'
  get '/contact', to: 'pages#contact'
end
```

and I created the file views/user/show.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

If you check the server logs, you might see devise complaining about unpermitted params. You'll need to permit all the required keys at once.

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :phone, :schoolNumber, :surname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation])
```